# Print uppercase occurrence in new column

Tags: bash, awk, grep, uppercase

"file1.txt" looks like this:

```
_1ss4TG actaaAAAACAAGTAAGCGTAATTCCTCCtagataataaaTTTACTAGTtata
osa-miR5523_L-1R+1  actaaAAAACAAGTAAGacatGAGGAGGAACATATTTACTAGTtata
ath-miR156a-5p  ggaggTGACAGAatgcgtgctcaccctctatctgtcaccccc
```

I would like to print the UPPERCASE occurrence in a third column, so it would look like this:

```
_1ss4TG actaaAAAACAAGTAAGCGTAATTCCTCCtagataataaaTTTACTAGTtata   33
osa-miR5523_L-1R+1  actaaAAAACAAGTAAGacatGAGGAGGAACATATTTACTAGTtata 34
ath-miR156a-5p  ggaggTGACAGAatgcgtgctcaccctctatctgtcaccccc  7
```

I have tried with grep and awk, but I haven't got it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{NF+=1;$3=length(gensub("[a-z]","","g",$2))}1' b
_1ss4TG actaaAAAACAAGTAAGCGTAATTCCTCCtagataataaaTTTACTAGTtata 33
osa-miR5523_L-1R+1 actaaAAAACAAGTAAGacatGAGGAGGAACATATTTACTAGTtata 34
ath-miR156a-5p ggaggTGACAGAatgcgtgctcaccctctatctgtcaccccc 7
```

Comment: perhaps some elaboration for future visitors?

Comment: Excelent! I don't quite understand the answer, but it works perfectly.